# Strongloop Loopback Native SQL

Tags: mysql, roles, relationships, loopbackjs

I have the following situation in a loopback application:

1. I have a 'Person' class that extends from built in 'User'
2. I have students ('Person' class with Role 'student')
3. I have teachers ('Person' class with Role 'teacher')
4. I have classgroups (ClassGroup class related to Person class with hasManyAndBelongsTo)

Students and Teachers are added to classgroups in the same way. Teachers can have multiple classgroups, students not. If I want to see all the students that are in the same classgroups, as a teacher, I use a remote method on Person. In that method I use the following SQL (21 is the id of the teacher):

```
SELECT * FROM `Person`
JOIN `ClassGroupPerson` 
    ON `Person`.`id` = `ClassGroupPerson`.`personId` 
JOIN `RoleMapping` 
    ON `RoleMapping`.`principalType` = "USER" 
    AND `RoleMapping`.`principalId` = `Person`.`id`
JOIN `Role` 
    ON `Role`.`name` = "student" 
    AND `Role`.`id` = `RoleMapping`.`roleId`
WHERE 
    `ClassGroupPerson`.`classGroupId` IN (
        SELECT `classGroupId` 
        FROM `ClassGroupPerson` 
        WHERE `personId` = 21
    )
```

In the documentation, it says, that using native Mysql is discouraged (http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Executing+native+SQL).

How would I achieve the same result in 'Loopback-style'. I've tried with filters, include, hasManyTrough, ... -stuff but I'm not able to achieve the same result?

Extra question: the result from this are JSON objects, how can I convert those easily into Person objects?

**EDIT**

With the following code in my remote method, I'm getting close:

```
Person.find({
    include: {
        relation: 'classgroups',
        scope: {
            include: {
                relation: 'people'
            }
        }
    },
    where: {
        id: id
    }
}, function(err, people){
    cb(err, people);
});
```

I have as a result: my teacher, with his classgroups included, and with each classgroup, I have the connected persons (teachers and students). The problem that remains, is that the teacher is also included in the classrooms, so I should be able to filter the result by Role = 'student', and I don't see how to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're asking, because I don't think you can filter relations based on attributes of the related model's other relations.  It wouldn't be impossible to implement that kind of functionality if you were willing to get your hands dirty though.

Comment: I've found an issue on github where the same functionality is suggested: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/942